# Twilio JS Web Client - Trouble with placing and receiving calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I'm working my way through the Twilio Client Javascript Quickstart using PHP. I am not a developer but am working my way learning PHP and JS as I go.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/client/javascript#gather-twilio-account-information

https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/client-quickstart-php

I'm able to place and receive calls seperately with a bit of reconfiguration between incoming or outgoing. When having my incoming voice url pointing to voice.php I'm able to place outgoing calls from the browser. I'm not able to call into the browser though.

```
    <?php
include('/home/bitnami/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/autoload.php');
include('/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/config.php');

use Twilio\Twiml;

$response = new Twiml;

// get the phone number from the page request parameters, if given
if (isset($_REQUEST['To']) && strlen($_REQUEST['To']) > 0) {
    $number = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['To']);
    $dial = $response->dial(array('callerId' => $TWILIO_CALLER_ID));

    // wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
    // by checking if the number given has only digits and format symbols
    if (preg_match("/^[\d\+\-\(\) ]+$/", $number)) {
        $dial->number($number);
    } else {
        $dial->client($number);
    }
} else {
    $response->say("Thanks for calling!");
}

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $response;
```

Now if I write a short bit of Twiml and point my voice URL to that XML file then I can call into the browser. I'm having trouble combining the two. I've been trying to modify the voice.php to also return the twiml to connect to my JS client but not having any luck.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You have code that can be used to make outgoing calls from Client (the PHP you've posted in the question) and some XML that direct incoming calls into your Client.

The good news is that you've pretty much done all the work.

When you setup a [capability token for outgoing calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/capability-tokens) you give it a [TwiML application](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/runtime/twiml-apps) SID. The TwiML application should point voice calls to your PHP.

When you setup a number to receive incoming calls you do not need to use the TwiML application for this, or even the same URL. You can edit your phone number to point the incoming voice call webhook directly at the XML that directs calls into your Client.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi Phil, maybe I was going at this the wrong way. I was trying to use a single number to be able to call from the browser to a real phone, and also from the real phone to the browser.  

I've got it working with using two numbers. I have one number linked to my TwiML app for making calls from the browser, the second number points to the XML to connect the call to my client. I've changed the callerID param so that when I make calls from the browser it shows up as the 2nd number so calls can be returned.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need the number to be linked to the TwiML app. That linking is done by the Capability Token. You only set the callerID on the outgoing call, so your first number in this case is just not being used and you could release it.